# Juliaの配列で、○○から～一番後ろまで選択するにはどうすればいいですか？

Tags: julia

Juliaの配列で、特定の位置から最後まで選択するにはどうすればいいですか？

たとえば、pythonで

```py
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a[2:]
# [3, 4, 5]
```

Rubyで

```rb
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a[2..]
```

と書くようなものをどう書けばよいのでしょうか？
一応下記のものは思いついたのですが、これより簡単な書き方がありそうな気がしています。

```
a[3:length(a)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

全てに使えるわけでは無いようですが、`end`というのがあるようです。

[How to split array in Julia like in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55138459/9014308) の回答

> Assume you have:
>
> ```
> julia> x = [[i] for i in 1.0:5.0]
> 5-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}:
>  [1.0]
>  [2.0]
>  [3.0]
>  [4.0]
>  [5.0]
> ```
>
> (this is an equivalent of you have written above but with the types you request).

途中省略

> You can use `end` to indicate end of your collection:
>   コレクションの終了を示すために`end`が使用できます：
>
> ```
> julia> x[3:end]
> 3-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}:
>  [3.0]
>  [4.0]
>  [5.0]
> ```

途中省略

> The difference is that with `@view` macro you can still use `end`, e.g. `@view x[2:end]`, but `view` function does not support it.
>   違いは、`@view`マクロでは`end`を引き続き使用できますが(たとえば`@view x[2:end]`) `view`関数ではサポートされないことです。

他にはテーマは違うようですが、こんな記事もあるようです。

[Array range complement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42382210/9014308)
[Julia's Negative/Complement Indexing like R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52378061/9014308)